# What is the difference between 360 panoramic images vs normal images

Tags: image, image-processing

I want to do face and plate blur. I use https://github.com/understand-ai/anonymizer on Docker.

Some images could process even though not all faces and plates blurred.

Some images cannot be process at all.

And all images are 360 panoramic images.

My question is why normal images are easy to undergo blurring process while 360 panoramic images are not easy to process?

Normal images in jpg format same goes with 360 panoramic images in jpg format. Width and height are same respectively.

What makes them different? what else differences between them other than their view?

Comment: For panormas, the closer you get to the poles, the more distorted the image becomes. The distortion depends on the type of projection and the size of the features (compared to the overall image), so without examples, we can't say much.

Comment: "cannot be processed at all" -- what does this mean? Do you get an error message? Is the image accepted but not changed? Are you getting wrong results?